# How Can I use a function multiple times on the same page?

Tags: php, function-declaration

Say this piece of code:

```
 <?php while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($resultuser)){ ?>
 <?php 

   function my_function($variable) {
      //do something here...
    }
 ?>
<?php };?>
```

This will obviously return this error

> Cannot redeclare my_function() previously declared

So what if someone needs to use the same function multiple times across the same page? Is there a way to generate random function() names? Any idea how to get around this? Thanks.

**EDIT WITH ACTUAL CODE**

```
    <?php while($deposit26=mysqli_fetch_array($resultdeposit26)){ ?>
<td  data-th="Hours">
    <?php 
        $week1hours = $deposit26['hours_worked'];
        $week2hours = $deposit26['hours_worked_wk2'];
        function time_to_decimal($time) {
        $timeArr = explode(':', $time);
        $decTime = ($timeArr[0] + ($timeArr[1]/60) + ($timeArr[2]/3600));
        return $decTime;
        }
        $groupd26hours = time_to_decimal($week1hours) + time_to_decimal($week2hours);
        echo round($groupd26hours, 2);
     ?>
</td>
  <?php };?>
```

Comment: You need to post more of your code.

Comment: @user2182349: you are right. I will update with the actual real code so you can see. I was just trying to make it short and simple.

Comment: @user2182349: Edit made. I'm actually populating table rows. Would this still fit your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
// Earlier in the file or included with include or require
function time_to_decimal($time) {
        $timeArr = explode(':', $time);
        $decTime = ($timeArr[0] + ($timeArr[1]/60) + ($timeArr[2]/3600));
        return $decTime;
} ?>
```

...

```
    <?php while($deposit26=mysqli_fetch_array($resultdeposit26)) : ?>
    <td  data-th="Hours">
    <?php 
        $week1hours = $deposit26['hours_worked'];
        $week2hours = $deposit26['hours_worked_wk2'];
        $groupd26hours = time_to_decimal($week1hours) +   time_to_decimal($week2hours);
        echo round($groupd26hours, 2); ?>
    </td>
    <?php endwhile ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to *declare the function* outside the loop and *call it* inside

```
<?php 
  function my_function($variable) {
  //do something here...
}

while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($resultuser)){ 
  my_function($variable);
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try and explain what I think could help.  I think a good starting point would be to look into including a script or including a script once in your files that require your function logic.  That way multiple files can take advantage of the same logic without it having to be repeated.  For example:

```
<?php 
// File functions.php
function my_function($variable) {
  ...  
} 
?>

<?php
// File one
include_once "functions.php"

...
// Use my_function() from file one
my_function($var);
?>

<?php
// File two
include_once "functions.php"

...
// Use my_function() from file two
my_function($var);
?>
```